# combined experiments consisting sub-experiments which became dependent on each other

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

The following is stated in the [Papoulis](https://books.google.com/books?id=cUmiDAEACAAJ&dq=Probability,+Random+Variables,+and+Stochastic+Processes+4th+edition+cartesian+product+of+two+experiments&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDiefH46T3AhVThv0HHVX0AgAQ6AF6BAgKEAI)' book   (p. 48)

> If we have two probability spaces ${(Ω_1, F_1, P_1)}$ and ${(Ω_2, F_2, P_2)}$,
> **whether  these two experiments are independent or dependent**, the
> probability space of the combined experiment, which consists of those
> two experiments, will be ${(Ω_1 × Ω_2, F, P)}$. To complete our new
> probability model, it is sufficient to assign the values of the
> probability function P as follows:
> $${P(A×Ω_2 )=P_1 (A) \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(1)}$$
> $${P(Ω_1×B)=P_2 (B)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (2)}$$

But in the following example, where we have a combined experiment consisting of two **dependent** random experiments, the assignments (1) and (2) leads to a contradiction.

---

Suppose that we have two types of dice - one is fair, the other is not:

1. Dice $A$ with probability space ${(Ω_1, F_1, P_1)}$

   - ${A_i}$: The event is that by throwing the dice $A$, the number $i$ will come
   - ${P_1 (A_6 )=1/6}$
2. Dice $B$ with probability space ${(Ω_2, F_2, P_2)}$

   - ${B_i}$: The event is that by throwing the dice $B$, the number $i$ will come
   - ${P_2 (B_6 )=1/10}$

Our combined experiment is  as follows: In a weird casino, two dice are rolled at the same time and both dice always return the same result.

In this experiment, The probability space will be ${(Ω_1 × Ω_2, F, P)}$ and :
$${P(A_1×B_6 )=P(A_2×B_6 )=⋯=P(A_5×B_6 )=0}$$
$${P(A_6×B_1 )=P(A_6×B_2 )=⋯=P(A_6×B_5 )=0}$$
According to relations (1) and (2):
$${P(A_6×Ω_2 )=P_1 (A_6 )=1/6}$$
$${P(Ω_1×B_6 )=P_2 (B_6 )=1/10}$$

(notice that $P(Ω_1×B_6 ) \neq {P(A_6×Ω_2 )}$)

According to the law of total probability:
$${P(Ω_1×B_6 )=P(A_1×B_6 )+P(A_2×B_6 )+⋯+P(A_6×B_6 )}$$
$${P(A_6×Ω_2 )=P(A_6×B_1 )+P(A_6×B_2 )+⋯+P(A_6×B_6 )}$$

So we have:
$${P(Ω_1×B_6 )=P(A_6×B_6 )}$$
$${P(A_6×Ω_2 )=P(A_6×B_6 )}$$

That is, we have:
$${P(Ω_1×B_6 )=P(A_6×Ω_2 )=1/6}$$

Here we encounter a contradiction:

- Papoulis assumptions say:     $\qquad\qquad{P(Ω_1×B_6 )≠P(A_6×Ω_2 ) }$
- the Kolmogorov axioms compel:      $\;\;\quad{P(Ω_1×B_6 )=P(A_6×Ω_2 )}$

---

now If we want to summarize:
We used Papoulis' assumptions (relations $(1)$ and $(2)$), but by applying the axioms of probability, I finally came to conflicting conclusions with our assumptions.

My question is: Is it really correct to apply assignments $(1)$ and $(2)$ if the sub-experiments of a combined experiment are dependent? (However, my calculations in this example show that this is not good practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Too long for a comment.**

Papoulu's definition is not quite complete, or right for that matter. He is simply trying to say (in a rather unreadable manner) that *a probability space* for a combination of two experiments is the Cartesian product and the probability measure in this space is *any measure* with marginal probability function those of the individual experiments. *This wrong in the sense that this is far from specifying a probability space*, indeed, there may be infinitely many probability spaces where conditions (1) and (2) occur and both conditions are not enough to specify a probability measure.

In regards to your example, experiments 1 and 2 are incompatible to be combined as requested. Let $X$ the result of the first experiment and $Y$ that of the second. You are stating that $X$ and $Y$ always show the same number, this means that $X = Y.$ However, $P(X = 6) = 1/6$ while $P(Y = 6) = 1/10,$ which is clearly impossible. I have no idea why you brought Kolmogorov's axioms at the end, they don't compell anything, they simply state what are the *"axioms" defining probability measures.* Anyway, this is the problem of Papoulu's "definition", you have $X$ and $Y$ but it gives you no real way to combine them really. The most common way is to make them independent, that means $P(A_i \times B_j) = P(A_i) P(B_j),$ but there may be many more ways to combine them such that (1) and (2) hold (all these other ways will give rise to not independent experiments). As a side note, you should avoid the term "dependent" since it is not quite clear what that means, it can mean "correlation not zero" or "one is function of the other" or "not independent", these three properties are not as related as intuituion would suggest (e.g. there are random variables $X$ and functions $f(X)$ such that the correlation between $X$ and $f(X)$ is zero; or there are random variables $X = f(Y, Z)$ such that $X$ and $Z$ are independent, etc.).

Comment: The problem assumes that P1(A6)=1/6 and P2(B6)=1/10, in probability space 1 and probability space 2 respectively

Comment: Suppose we throw dice A on the ground, then we manually place dice B on the ground so that the same face comes up (for example, if by throwing dice A, face 6 happened, we manually  Place face 6 of the dice B on the ground.
This is a combined experiment with two different dice(not incompatible dice), which is practically feasible

Comment: notice that in the next comment by P(B6) I mean P(Ω1 * B6) not P2(B6); P(B6) means probability of B6 in the new probability space (combined space)

Comment: Now if I am asked what is the probability of face 6 of dice B, P(B6), I say 1/6; because the result of throwing dice B is completely dependent on dice A (in the combined experiment) and the probability of A6, P(A6), can intuitively be assigned to 1/6 ( =P1(A6) )

Comment: But if you ask Papoulis, he says that even in this new probability space (combined experiment), the probability of B6, P(B6), should be 1/10 ( =P2(B6) )

Comment: I can tell you are utterly confused with this but I have no idea on how to help you. Your intuition on what a combination of experiments seems to be completely wrong. The idea of combination is that if we look at the results of $B$ ignoring those of $A,$ we'd get the results of $B$ alone. That means that (2) holds. Similarly for (1). What you are doing in "throw a dice and then place the other on top with the same face up" is _not_ a combination, not intuitively, and certainly, not probabilistically. So, your intuition is plain wrong.

Comment: we have 2 different dice, 2 different probability space, and 2 different experiments which are combined into 1 probability space, 1 combined experiment; notice that we in a way have made one sub-experiment dependent on another and made a combined experiment that makes us doubt whether Papulis' talk about it can be true.

Comment: I guess the problem is that you are thinking it is backwards. The point of a "combination" of two experiments is that you can think of an experiment that occured beforehand and from that one, you go to the individual experiments in a consistent manner; what you are doing is believing you can start with any two experiments and combined them arbitrarily and the combination is indeed faithful. This is nonesense.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you are saying.

Do you mean that Papoulis says that we can use an existing combined probability space to create the probability space of each of its constituent sub-experiments (moving from a combined experiment to its sub-experiments)? And there have been no discussion at all about how to make the probability space of a combined experiment from the probability space of some existing sub-experiments (moving from sub-experiment to a combined experiment involving them)

Comment: If so, thank you very much for helping me

Comment: That is correct. Except simple discrete examples, there will be infinitely many "combined" experiments that give rise to the individual ones. Technically, what you have is $\Omega = \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2,$ $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{F}_1 \otimes \mathscr{F}_2$ and you want $\mathbf{P}$ here such that $\mathrm{pr}_1(\mathbf{P}) = \mathbf{P}_1$ and $\mathrm{pr}_2(\mathbf{P}) = \mathbf{P}_2,$ where the $\mathrm{pr}_i(\omega_1,\omega_2) = \omega_i$ are the projections. This cannot fully specify $\mathbf{P}.$ (And $T(\mu) (H) = \mu(T^{-1}(H)),$ for function $T,$ measure $\mu$ and event $H.$)

Comment: Think of the joint distribution function $F.$ What Papoulus is saying is that $F$ is a "combined" experiment if $F_1(x) = \int_y F$ and $F_2(y) = \int_x F$ coincide with the individual distributions given in advance. This cannot tell you what is $F(x,y)$ for any $(x,y).$ You need to know more about $F.$ For example, if you knew the experiments were independent, then $F(x,y) = F_1(x) F_2(y).$ But generally, you cannot tell anything about $F.$

Comment: thank you, I got my answer; But just out of curiosity, you said: "Except simple discrete examples", therefore could you give such an example which is combined experiment but don't give rise to the individual ones?